# AJAX PHP response interpretation

Tags: php, ajax

I noticed that there are several ways for an AJAX call made by jQuery to interpret data. I had a look at json, but maybe it is an over complication for what I am trying to do.

My php script ALWAYS returns a 1 integer string SOMETIMES followed by a 1 integer int OR a 2 integer int.

So it can either return

`x` or `xy` or `xyz`

where `x`, `y`, and `z` are real single numbers.

How could I decode this response and assign `jQuery` var to the reply. I was thinking something like.

```
var code = firstNumberOf response
var value = secondNumberOf and thirdNumberOff response
```

But `var value` can also just be the second number if there is only a second number and not a third one.

Thanks in advance, I have been dwelling on this for ages.

Comment: I'd delimit the data woth commas or something, so you can simply split it. Otherwise JSON. Not too keen on clumping values together like that!!

Comment: what do you mean by `and` in the value there? A boolean AND? Addition?

Comment: And I agree with @Luke, this is not a good way to display data.

Comment: Okay, so i added a comma after the first integer. How would i go about splitting it?

Comment: @Semger response.split(",");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just treating the response string as an array?

```
$.get( "page.php", function( data ) {
    var response = data;
    response.length; //number of digits
    response[0]; //first digit
    response[1]; //second digit
    var value = response[1] + (response.length>2?response[2]:0);
});
```